# Django Rest Framework : prefetch_related doesnot work as expected with serializer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have two models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

class Author(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

then a `prefetch_related` queryset is created as follows

```
Author.objects.all().prefetch_related("book_set")
```

Then a serializer is created for the `Author` and `book_set` is added to serializer field like this

```
class AuthorSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name' ,'book_set')
```

But this only return list of book ids as nested serializer and not the rest of data with it such as name like below.

```
{
name:'john',
book_set:[1,2,3]

}
```

Is there any way to solve this to get the data as

```
name:'john',
book_set:[{id:1,name:'Book 1'},{id:2,name:'Book 2'},{id:3,name:'Book 3'}]

}
```

Also what to do if I have to further filter these prefetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate serializer for the book model. Something like this:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'


class AuthorSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book_set = BookSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name' ,'book_set')
```

In general, foreign key and many to many relationships always require the other model to have its own serializer or you will only ever just get a list of ids.